# Vector gives 0 as output when out of bounds?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

I was playing around with nested vectors and printing random elements to see the output and I noticed that when I go out of bounds I don't get an error. I simply get 0 returned as the value.

Why is this?

Is the vector being resized and initialized to zero whenever I attempt to call an out-of-bounds element by index?

Here's the code I was running:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


int main(){
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix;
  std::vector<int> temp;
  temp.push_back(1);
  temp.push_back(2);
  matrix.push_back(temp);
  std::cout << matrix[0][45] << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're having undefined behavior, that it prints `0` is just a mere coincidence.

Comment: Thanks! Is there anyway that I can make it give me an error?

Comment: @Hadi check the boundaries and respond accordingly

Comment: @Hadi Use `at()` instead of `[]`: `vector.at(0)`

Comment: @Hadi `matrix.at(0).at(45)`

Comment: `at` will throw an exception but I'd still check boundaries instead. (where applicable at least)